# asp.net validation spacing is messed up with 2 validation controls on a textbox

Tags: asp.net, validation

asp.net validation spacing is messed up with 2 validation controls on a textbox.

I tried playing with display static/dynamic but that didn't work.

ideas?

**Update**
What is happening is this, if the 2nd validation control displays its message, the 1st validation is using up some white space as a placeholder for its message.  So there is a huge gap between the control and the error message.
If the 1st validations controls message is displayed, it looks just fine.

Comment: We are going to need some more detail here.  What is "messed up", what is the layout like?

Comment: Can you post some code? Display="dynamic" should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display should be set to dynamic for both of these controls.  From the sounds of it the first validation control has this property set to static.